# Ansi escape codes BG color is working, but text color isnt[Trinket.io]

Tags: python, colors

```
import os


column= {"h":1,"g":2,"f":3,"e":4,"d":5,"c":6,"b":7,"a":8}
os.system("")

Board = [
    " ","H","G","F","E","D","C","B","A"," ","",
    "1","R","N","B","Q","K","B","N","R","1","",
    "2","P","P","P","P","P","P","P","P","2","",
    "3"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","3","",
    "4"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","4","",
    "5"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","5","",
    "6"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","6","",
    "7","P","P","P","P","P","P","P","P","7","",
    "8","R","N","B","Q","K","B","N","R","8","",
    " ","H","G","F","E","D","C","B","A"," "
]

def showBoard():
  showBoarding = []
  for i in range(len(Board)):
    if i%2 == 0:
      showBoarding.append("\033[2;32;47m" + Board[i]) 
    else:
      showBoarding.append("\033[1;37;40m" + Board[i]) 
  return(showBoarding)

def printBoard():
  showBoarder = showBoard()
  for i in range(0,10):
    print('  '.join(map(str, showBoarder[i*11:i*11+10])))
```

Ansi escape code is working for background color, but foreground color isnt working, why is this?

I've tried changing the text color and it still stays black, im using trinket.io, since my school blocked replit

Comment: There's a library for this: https://pypi.org/project/ansi/